# Deleting element from a long object

Tags: javascript, css

I have an object that looks like this:

```
[{"1":{"name":"A","email":2}},
{"2":{"name":"B","email":3}},
{"3":{"name":"C","email":4}},]
{"4":{"name":"B","email":5}}]
```

I want to have a result like below:

```
 [{"name":"A","email":2}},
   {"name":"B","email":3}},
   {"name":"C","email":4}},]
   {"name":"B","email":5}}]
```

I tried but this code is not working, now I am a bit lost as to how to approach a solution for this.

```
obj.map(a => {
  var newobj
   a = []
   a.push[a]
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to read about `Array.prototype.map()` and the way you use it is not the proper way

```js
 var homework =[{"1":{"name":"A","email":2}},
                  {"2":{"name":"B","email":3}},
                  {"3":{"name":"C","email":4}},
                  {"4":{"name":"B","email":5}}];

var outputofthehomework = homework.map( s => Object.values(s)[0] );
console.log(outputofthehomework)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = [{"1":{"name":"A","email":2}},{"2":{"name":"B","email":3}}, {"3":{"name":"C","email":4}}, {"4":{"name":"B","email":5}}];

var b = [];   
a.forEach(function(element){
    for (var key in element){
          b.push(element[key]);
    }      
});

console.log(b)
```